# jQuery Load XML and Refresh Based on XML Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am building a player for an online radio station.  The stream is providing an XML file that displays the current song information.  This XML file is hosted on the stream server which is NOT the server the website is running on.

Here is a sample of whats in the XML.  Lets pretend it comes from http://randomserver/station.xml

```
<playlist>
<stationCallSign>KCXR</stationCallSign>
<programType>PGM</programType>
<mediaType>AUD</mediaType>
<title>Break Free</title>
<artist>Decyfer Down</artist>
<album>End of Grey</album>
<cover>
http://cdnrf.securenetsystems.net/file_radio/album_art/O/1/5/51Oo0rBqATL.jpg
</cover>
<duration>199</duration>
<campaignId/>
<fileId/>
<programStartTS>30 Sep 2015 17:48:22</programStartTS>
<adBlockPos>1</adBlockPos>
</playlist>
```

I need to pull that data to display it on the webpage and then refresh everything based on how many seconds are in the "duration" field.  Essentially refresh all of this when the song changes.

Here is the html output I need.

```
<div id="playerDiv" class="player-div" style="display: block;">
            <div id="album-art">
            <img id="now-playing-album-art" src="http://cdnrf.securenetsystems.net/file_radio/album_art/e/1/5/51eeZTxMYuL.jpg" class="player-div-img cP" width="250" height="250" title="">
            </div>

    <div id="now-playing" class="now-playing tS">
        <span id="now-playing-title" class="menuHeader f15em">Lights Out</span> - <span id="now-playing-artist">Silverline</span>
        <div id="now-playing-album">Lights Out</div>
    </div>

            [playercode]
</div>
```

I was hoping to use the mobile jquery so that this functions well on mobile devices.

Comment: Are you wanting to fully refresh the page or just a timer to know when to pull the next station.xml down?

Comment: Just refresh the xml content and update the current song information without reloading the entire page.  Reloading the whole page would reload the player as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to do a little more research into ajax requests.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.ajax('http://randomserver/station.xml', {
       success: function() { //Parse xml and update document },
       error: function() { //handle error }
   }
}, songDuration);
```

With jQuery you can easily download your xml file and update the song

In the above code `setTimeout(callback,timeInMillis)` allows you to set a time in milliseconds for the callback to occur. The callback then makes an `XMLHTTPRequest` to the url of your choice and then updates the page if it is successful in getting the page.

You can use the default Javascript XML parser to parse the response you get from the server.

**Resources Used:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Created a Fiddle trying to piece this together.  But I'm missing something, obviously as it doesn't work.  http://jsfiddle.net/syvo1yxg/

Comment: I did a little updating.. You really should do some actual reading on the ajax functions and XMLHttpRequest in general and get a bit more familiar with Javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/syvo1yxg/2/